# set up the database with initial data for testing

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, testing, h2

i have a spring boot project that save some entities to the database and retirve them,
i want to make repository test cases so i'm using h2 database for testing but the problem i want to initialize the database before each test class with some data to use them in testing.
i have more than one test class each test class should drop all the tables and create them again using hibernate and initialize the database with initial data for testing.

i tried 2 solution
1- using `@SQL()` on the test class, it worked but the problem of it for every test in the class the spring execute the sql statments and that will make the database grow very fast and have alot of doublicates and i don't want that i want the sql statments to be executed once only before running any test method of the class.
2- setting the sql statments to the propreites file of the tests, i will work but in this case i should add all the statments used for all classes in one place and for every class the database will be full with all the data not just the data it needs for this test class.